# Ionic Autostart plugin issue. App shows blank page after adding it

Tags: javascript, android, ionic-framework, autostart

I want my ionic app to run automatically when phone is turned on. I need it for Android platform only.

I added the "Autostart" plugin as it is described in this documentation:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/autostart

I did not get any build issues.

Now when app is run it does not show anything, just blank page.
Can somebody help to troubleshoot this issue?